# Parse JSON array into list

Tags: java, json

What is the quickest way to parse this json array into a list?

```
[
    ["FundRequest"],
    ["nOS"],
    ["NEX"],
    ["DREP"],
    ["ChromaWay"],
    ["Jura"],
    ["Origo"],
    ["Phantasma"],
    ["NuCypher"],
    ["Oasis Labs"]
]
```

Its being generated from the following code:

```
private void getNames(String spreadsheetUrl) {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
    String result = json.get("values").toString();
    log.debug("Found: {}", result);
}
```

The output is from the following json response:

```
{
  "range": "Frontpage!E6:E15",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "FundRequest"
    ],
    [
      "nOS"
    ],
    [
      "NEX"
    ],
    [
      "DREP"
    ],
    [
      "ChromaWay"
    ],
    [
      "Jura"
    ],
    [
      "Origo"
    ],
    [
      "Phantasma"
    ],
    [
      "NuCypher"
    ],
    [
      "Oasis Labs"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: is it array of strings or array of arrays?

Comment: it might be an array of arrays. im just trying to get extract the string in each case and save it to a list

Comment: What value are getting in result variable ?

Comment: i get: `[
    ["FundRequest"],
    ["nOS"],
    ["NEX"],
    ["DREP"],
    ["ChromaWay"],
    ["Jura"],
    ["Origo"],
    ["Phantasma"],
    ["NuCypher"],
    ["Oasis Labs"]
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like GSON:

Install it with maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

If you're trying to parse this:

```
{
  "range": "Frontpage!E6:E15",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "FundRequest"
    ],
    [
      "nOS"
    ],...
```

as a java object then create a wrapper class for your json entity:

```
public class Wrapper {

    private String range;
    private String majorDimension;
    private List<?> values;

    /**
     * @return the range
     */
    public String getRange() {
        return range;
    }
    /**
     * @return the values
     */
    public List<?> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
    /**
     * @param values the values to set
     */
    public void setValues(List<?> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
    /**
     * @return the majorDimension
     */
    public String getMajorDimension() {
        return majorDimension;
    }
    /**
     * @param majorDimension the majorDimension to set
     */
    public void setMajorDimension(String majorDimension) {
        this.majorDimension = majorDimension;
    }
    /**
     * @param range the range to set
     */
    public void setRange(String range) {
        this.range = range;
    }
}
```

Then using GSON you can parse a Json string into a wrapper object:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Wrapper w = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Wrapper.class);
```

Check this: http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/

**EDIT:**

If you're trying to parse this:

```
[
    ["FundRequest"],
    ["nOS"],
    ["NEX"],
    ["DREP"],
    ["ChromaWay"],
    ["Jura"],
    ["Origo"],
    ["Phantasma"],
    ["NuCypher"],
    ["Oasis Labs"]
]
```

As an array of arrays, then using gson you can do:

```
    List<?> arr = gson.fromJson("[[\"FundRequest\"],[\"nOS\"],...]", List.class);
    System.out.println(arr);
```

The println shall print:
    [[FundRequest], [nOS], ...]

The json array of arrays shall be parsed as a list of lists

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi I tried this and I get the following error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 37 path $.values[0]

Comment: Are you trying to parse this `[    ["FundRequest"],    ["nOS"],` ...` or this: `{
  "range": "Frontpage!E6:E15",  "majorDimension": "ROWS",  "values": [          FundRequest"    ], ... ` ?